# How to transform Iterator[String] into a Reader instance for parsing?

Tags: java, scala, parsing, iterator

I have memory issues and I wonder what the best way is to parse a file with low memory foot print. Right now I have this, an Iterator[String]

```
val myIterator: Iterator[String] = io.Source.fromURL("http://somewebsite.com/download/bigFile.txt").getLines().filter(isValidInput)
```

Now I want to parse it.

```
val result = MyParser.parseAll(MyParser.line, ???)
```

It needs a `java.io.Reader` and I already tried a `StringReader` but that kills my computer. Is there a way to transform an Iterator into a Reader?

I also tried the following but my result after parsing is 0. So I suppose I'm doing something wrong.

```
import java.io.{BufferedReader, InputStreamReader}
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

val stream: InputStream = new SequenceInputStream({
  val i = myIterator map { s => new ByteArrayInputStream(s.getBytes("UTF-8")) }
  i.asJavaEnumeration
})
val in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream))

val result = MyParser.parseAll(MyParser.line, in)
```

Comment: `new InputStreamReader(new URL("http://...").openStream)`

Comment: I consumed the Iterator in my code somewhere else so that was the problem in my second try to parse it. It tries to parse but my computer freezes while doing it. That's probably no solution to the problem either.

Comment: @Dima I do some filtering before I want to parse. A reason for this is to trash all the not needed lines and to make the Parser not overly complicated. Is there a way to create an InputStreamReader, BufferedReader etc from a List[String] or Iterator[String]?

Comment: Well, that's what your second snippet does (as along as you don't consume the iterator). Seems rather backwards, but ... whatever works.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a `PagedSeqReader`, provided by Scala:

```
import scala.util.parsing.input.PagedSeqReader
import scala.collection.immutable.PagedSeq 

MyParser.parseAll(
  MyParser.line, 
  new PagedSeqReader(PagedSeq.fromLines(myIterator)))
```

Note that parsing with Scala's parsing-combinators library may require random access, because of backtracking. I don't know how well `PagedSeq` deals with this, and if it wouldn't eventually try to load the whole `Iterator` into memory, even when using a parser that does no backtracking. In that case, doing what you are trying to do may be impossible.

Answer (score 0):

If your parser can parse one line at a time, do: `myIterator map { l => MyParser.parseAll(MyParser.line, l) }` to get an `Iterator[ParserResult[X]]`